# ui-router: default route based on user role

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI router in my project. The home page of my application consists of 4 tabs, each routing to a different template. This is my current routing code, im using a forEach to create 6 routes.

```
['Draft','Assigned','InProgress','Completed','Rejected','All'].forEach(function (val) {
        $stateProvider.state({
            name: 'root.jobs.list.' + val.toLowerCase(),
            url: '/' + val.toLowerCase(),
            views: {
                'currentTab': {
                    templateUrl: 'adminworkspace/jobs',
                    controller: 'JobsController'
                }
            },
            data: {
                userJobsStatus: val
            }
        });
    });
```

By default when the user logs in, it goes to "root.jobs.list.draft". How do redirect to a given state based on the logged in user's role (Admin, User, Clerk etc..). If want to redirect all users that are part of the "Engineer" or "Lead Engineer" role to **"root.jobs.list.inprogress"**

I originally had this in the controller, but as you can see, it didn't work, because each time I clicked on a tab, it always routes back to **"root.jobs.list.inprogress"**

```
    if (user !== undefined) {
        if (user.BusinessRole == "Engineer" || user.BusinessRole == "Lead Engineer")
            $state.go('root.jobs.list.inprogress');
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I already have had to solve that :

I've registered a state that was used only to handle the default page based on the role.

```
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider.state("default", {
            url:"/",
            templateUrl: "app/core/home/default.html",
            controller: "DefaultController"
        });
```

The the controller was simply :

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("core").controller("DefaultController", [
        "$rootScope",
        "$state",
        "roles",
        function ($rootScope, $state, roles) {
            if ($rootScope.hasPermission(roles.SomeRoleName)) {
                $state.go("someStateName");
            } else if ($rootScope.hasPermission(roles.SomeRoleName)) {
                $state.go("someStateName");
            }
        }
    ]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the link of the default state is same for each role e.g **/user/home** for both **admin** and **user**. 
One thing we can do is to show different html templates in the default state of the app based on roles. ui-router provides @stateProvider service which has properties templateProvider and ControllerProvider properties. We can use them to figure out which template and controller we want to use for same default state. [Here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) is the documentation link.