# AngularJS multiple permission management

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new with AngularJs framework, I want to quest for a problem with the routing logic. I have an application with 3 type of clients : Top Manager, Local warehouse manager and central warehouse manager. I use to route the application this code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "viewHome/main.html",
    })
    .when("/indexProduct", {
        templateUrl: "viewIndex/indexProduct.html",
    })
    .when("/indexCategory", {
        templateUrl: "viewIndex/indexCategory.html",
    })
    .when("/indexCompare", {
        templateUrl: "viewIndex/indexCompare.html",
    });
});
```

I would to know if there is a mode to route the client in different view, based on the permission of authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ui-router: default route based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003470/ui-router-default-route-based-on-user-role)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stateProvider
  .when('userManagement', {
    [...]
    data: {
      permissions: {
        only: ['ADMIN','MODERATOR']
      }
    }
  });
```

There is a useful library for this purpose, check it out [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission)